# Rectangle from absolute position to page width

Tags: html, css, svg

Concretely: I want to draw a rectangle on a website that has height 100px, say, whose left end is at 100px, say, and that goes on to the right side of the website (without making the page width bigger).

I tried to do it by having an svg element of width 200px, say, that contains a rectangle of witdh 5000, but I don't know how to make the parent svg element not crop the rectangle:

```
<svg width="200" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100"><rect x="100" y="0" width="5000" height="100" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0)"></svg>
```

An alternative possibility would be if I could have something like width="100%-100px"

Note that this doesn't do what I want since the left end will vary depending on the page width:

```
<svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspecRatio="none"><rect x="100" y="0" width="5000" height="100" style="fill:rgb(255,0,0)"></svg>
```

One can certainly do it in hundrets of ways dynamically (using e.g. Java Script), but I'm looking for static solution.

Edit: the conrete problem is solved by Paulie_D and maioman below (via the "alternative possibility"). Still I would be interested in the following:

Abstractly: how can I have content draw beyond its bounding box?

Comment: It depends what you mean by 'draw'...if you give us an image of what you are after we can offer alternatives. Background colors and images outside of the boundaries are fairly simple but actual content is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious method is to position the div absolutely and use `calc` to set the width.

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

**Note...other options may exist depending on the actual nature of your requirement.**

Answer (score 1):

you can set width property with a value like:

```
  width: calc( 100% - 100px )
```