# Horizontally align rect inside larger svg to right

Tags: html, css, svg

I have an `svg` that contains a `rect` inside which is smaller in size. I want the `rect` to align right horizontally inside the `svg`. The following doesn't seem to work:

```html
<svg width="400" 
     height="110" 
     style="background: grey; 
     display: flex; 
     justify-content: flex-end"
>
    <rect width="200" 
        height="50" 
        style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);
        stroke-width:3;
        stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"
   />  
</svg>
```

Display `flex` and `justify-content` are not working when it's for an `svg`. I need to understand two things:

1. Why are `flex` styles not being applied to the `svg`?
2. How do I align the `rect` to the right of the `svg`?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try `transform: translate(25%,25%);` in rect to center rect

Comment: See answer here. I believe that's what you are looking for:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28678336/rectangle-from-absolute-position-to-page-width

Comment: No @Kosem I am not looking for that

Comment: @MdBalal right side you mean up down or center?

Comment: I just want the `rect` to be right aligned in the `svg`. Now it can be up, down or center - anything works as long as it is on the right side in the svg.

Comment: In SVG, you can only use a very limited number of CSS properties. See: https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/style.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `transform: translate();` to `rect`

```html
<h3>right up</h3>
<svg width="400" height="110" style="background: grey; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <rect width="200" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);transform: translate(49.5%,2%);" />  
</svg>
<h3>right down</h3>
<svg width="400" height="110" style="background: grey; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <rect width="200" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);transform: translate(49.5%,52%);" />  
</svg>
<h3>right center</h3>
<svg width="400" height="110" style="background: grey; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
  <rect width="200" height="50" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);transform: translate(49.5%,30%);" />  
</svg>
```

**Edit**

Use 
`x="" y=""`

```html
    <h3>right up</h3>
    <svg width="400" height="110" style="background: grey; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end">
      <rect width="200" height="50" x="198" y="2" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0);" />  
    </svg>
```

Comment: That's fine but why doesn't flex styles apply to svg?

Answer (score 1):

SVG don't have float,justify alignment elements like in html.

So you should either use

```
transform:translate();
```

Or while making svg you can give position using x and y coordinates.

```
<svg width="400" height="110" style="background: grey;">
<rect width="200" height="50" x="197" y="3" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

In SVG, you can only use a very [limited number of CSS properties](https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/style.html) compared to HTML. As such, SVG elements don't know anything about `display:flex`.

So in your example, `<rect>` simply ignores those CSS rules it doesn't understand.

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
  
  
  display: flex; /* Has no effect because <rect> doesn't understand display: flex */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Has no effect because <rect> doesn't understand justify-content: flex-end */
}

rect {
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="200" height="50"/>  
</svg>
```

---

### So you can do this with a [translate transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform#Translate)

> The translate(`<x> [<y>]`) transform function moves the object by x and y.  If y is not provided, it is assumed to be zero.

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}

rect {
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="200" height="50" transform="translate(197,0)"/> 
</svg>
```

### Or with an [x attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/x)

> This attribute determines the x coordinate of the rect.
>
> Value type: `<length>|<percentage>`

```css
svg {
  background: grey;
}

rect {
  fill: rgb(0, 0, 255);
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
    <rect width="200" height="50" x="197"/> 
</svg>
```